# How to filelock an entire directory?

Tags: python, file-locking

I want to lock a directory and its contents, to allow only one process writing in it.
To do that, I'm using the [Portalocker](https://portalocker.readthedocs.io/) library, and a file called `.lock`

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os
import portalocker as pl

DIRECTORY = Path('./protected')
p_lock = DIRECTORY / '.lock'
with pl.Lock(p_lock, 'w', timeout=10) as lock:
    # Writing pid to lock
    print(os.getpid(), file=lock)
    lock.flush()

    # do things that write to some files
    # inside DIRECTORY

    # Remove lock file
    p_lock.unlink()
```

As long as all the processes execute the same code, no two process will be in the critical section. This wasn't causing any problems, but now I want to make a reader process.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os
import portalocker as pl

DIRECTORY = Path('./protected')
p_lock = DIRECTORY / '.lock'
with pl.Lock(p_lock, 'r', timeout=10):
    # do things
```

This throws a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './protected/.lock'`, because the file is removed when the writer finishes.

**How can I make sure that either one process is writing, or multiple processes is reading to/from a directory?**

> Note: There is one writer process, and multiple readers (threads spawned from the same process, but not the same as the writer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with how portalocker deals with files - it tries to `open` them, which works when opening non-existing file in `'w'` mode, and fails in `'r'` mode.

The solution in your case is to manually create the file (and never remove it, it's a bad idea).

Writer:

```
with pl.Lock(p_lock, 'w'):
    # do things
    # don't remove the p_lock file
```

Reader:

```
p_lock.touch(exist_ok=True)
with pl.Lock(p_lock, 'r', flags=pl.LockFlags.SHARED | pl.LockFlags.NON_BLOCKING):
    # do things
    # don't remove the p_lock file
```

(and don't bother writing PID into the file, unless it's for your own debugging purpuses)

Comment: I left the pid because it's useful for some debugging scripts, but now instead fo `unlink` I do a `truncate` and it's working, thanks!